# DB2 admin cmd switch off auto commit

Tags: sql, db2

I want to execute this script but without commit, how to do it?

```
call SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD(
'LOAD FROM (SELECT * FROM A) OF CURSOR INSERT INTO B'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

No way.
`LOAD` implicitly commits a number of times during its execution, and you can't influence it.